# removeWhere in list of files

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

I have a File which contains all the names of all the files I've created and I decode it into a Map which then has the following formate:

```
{"fileList.json":"false",
"testwert_0_.json":"false",
"jakob_0_.json":"false",
"jakobjokoobus_0_.json":"true",
"jakobjokoobussss_0_.json":"false",
"jakobjokoobusssssss_0_.json":"true"}
```

Now I would like to delete all the entries from the map, which have the value set to "true".

It should be a simple problem, but I just can't wrap my head around the map.removeWhere() function.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```dart
// assumes your map is declared by 'm'
m.removeWhere((k, v) => v == "true");
```

The function is called for each key-value pair. You remove the ones with value `"true"`.

For other handy methods available for Maps and Objects in Dart [this article](https://dev.to/graphicbeacon/top-10-mapobject-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart--1ido) is worth a read.